# How to Identify magic number on boot partition?

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

After reading this snippet from [source](http://mbrwizard.com/thembr.php)

> Magic Number
> Located in the final two bytes of the MBR (511-512), this section must contain the hex value AA55, which officially classifies this as a valid MBR. An invalid magic number indicates a corrupt or missing MBR, therefore these bytes are critical to booting or using the disk.

With this information I wrote the following program to test:

```
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>


#define SECTOR_SIZE 512


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  int offset=0;int rc=-1;
  
  char *sector = aligned_alloc(SECTOR_SIZE,SECTOR_SIZE);
  memset(sector,'\0',SECTOR_SIZE);

  /*opening the src blk device*/
  int fd;
  if((fd=open("/dev/sda", O_RDWR |O_SYNC | O_DIRECT))==-1)
  {
     perror("open hdd:");
     return -1;
  }

  if(lseek(fd,offset,SEEK_SET)==-1)
  {
     perror("lseek hdd:");
     return -1;
  }

  rc = read(fd,sector,SECTOR_SIZE);

   /*used to identify whether the last two bytes of the first sector
    * contain the magic number to indicate it is bootable */
  if(sector[SECTOR_SIZE-1]==0xAA55 && sector[SECTOR_SIZE]==0xAA55)
  {
     printf("[+]Found bootable section magic bytes match\n");
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
   free(sector);
   close(fd);

   return 0;
  }
```

However When I compile and run.

> gcc -W -g -D_GNU_SOURCE example.c

I receive the following warnings and when I attempt to run the program anyway,
it doesn't output anything,thus the magic number hasn't been identified. I'm clearly missing something. I just quickly put this together after reading the
prior snipped from google and give it a go.

> example.c:40:26: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
> if(sector[SECTOR_SIZE-1]==0xAA55 && sector[SECTOR_SIZE]==0xAA55)
> ^~
> example.c:40:57: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
> if(sector[SECTOR_SIZE-1]==0xAA55 && sector[SECTOR_SIZE]==0xAA55)

**So comparison is false due to limited range of data type, but why, isn't
each sector 512 bytes?**

**Note**: running "parted -l" says my partition table is msdos(does this change things as prior source talks MBR) and sector size is 512B.

Comment: Isn't `char` one byte in size in c?  Consider using an array of `int16_t` rather than `char`, or evaluating each `char` independently.

Comment: Legacy-BIOS, MBR are synonyms. Since ~2015 mainstream MBs widely started supporting UEFI. Why not use `O_RDONLY` flag?

Comment: I'm trying to find it and overwrite it thus it can't be checked if it is boot-able. Thus can't boot up. It's a theoretical at the moment, to see if I It's possible in theory? So I'm still reading up on it, as an educational proof of concept. So still learning.

Comment: So you're saying the exert is false when it applies to UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `sector` is a `char*`, so `sector[<anything>]` is a `char`, i.e. 8-bits; and yet you are comparing it with 0xAA55, a 16-bit value. What you want is:

```
if(sector[SECTOR_SIZE-2]==0x55 && sector[SECTOR_SIZE-1]==0xAA)
```

Note also that the last two bytes of the sector are `SECTOR_SIZE-2` and `SECTOR_SIZE-1`, not `SECTOR_SIZE-1` and `SECTOR_SIZE`.

Comment: I understand now. The warnings have disappeared. However it's still not able to identify the magic number, which is the other issue. I would mark multiple answers if I could.

Comment: You should use a debugger to inspect the sector returned by `read`